# Flutter: How to access array data inside a Map?

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

I am developing a Flutter app and I am getting a JSON data like below

```
{chat_mode: supplier, timestamp: 1605852885271, last_message: Test, members: [K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0owwsABCD, K9ioYyiEUQVVNjx0owwsaXYZ]}
```

I need to access each individual element under `members` and this is what I tried.

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.value;
print(map["members"]);
```

The above allows me to access the entire array, not each record.

But i can't access the individual element by using something like `map["members"][0]` because it is a map. In this case, how can i access this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly convert it to a `List`

try

```
List<dynamic> members = List.of(map["members"]);
```

or

```
List<dynamic> members = map["members"];
```