# How do i get profileImagePath?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone help, i'm developing a flutter app and i have:

```
{userdetails: [{profileImagePath: https%3A%2F%2Ftinyfac.es%2Fdata%2Favatars%2F344CFC24-61FB-426C-B3D1-CAD5BCBD3209-200w.jpeg, firstName: Abdul, lastName: Bozak, gender: Monsieur}]}
```

and i want just profileImagePath.

When i try

```
widget.userDetails['userdetails'][0]['profileImagePath']
```

then i get this error:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: drop some more code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927867/flutter-how-to-access-array-data-inside-a-map

Comment: Thank you guys, but i was trying to not implement globalStatement, but it was inevitable ( Matrix refererence );